# Protecting from crashes (beyond bounds) with [object objectAtIndex:]

Tags: cocoa-touch, arrays

I'd like to know if there's a way to verify if an index exists before getting it.

So it'd be way to protect my code against:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (0)'
```

Like in PHP you can do: `isset($object[10]);` and it'll return true if it exists.

Is there such a method in Objective-C/Cocoa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you can check if the index is above the array's count before calling `-objectAtIndex:`.

```
if (i < [array count])
   do_something_with([array objectAtIndex:i]);
```

Unlike PHP, Objective-C's NSArray is really an array. The indices are always numeric and consecutive. (In ObjC the associative array is called NSDictionary.)